# Calling a Python Script from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, python, python-2.7, exec

I am trying to call a python script from my PHP page but no output is being delivered. Is there any error in code ?

```
<?php
include('main.php'); 
$lat = $_POST['lt'];
$lon = $_POST['ln'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$rad = $_POST['rd'];

$outs = 'python recommend.py ' . $uid . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . ' ' .     $rad;
$output = shell_exec($outs);
echo $output;
?>
```

Whereas I tried to get the output using dummy variables, it is being shown.

```
<?php
$lat = $_POST['lt'];
$lon = $_POST['ln'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$rad = $_POST['rd'];
echo        "11,28.720663,77.106192,1.18764869157,50.2058551405~12,28.705344,77.147270,2.854    76982119,2.42050298022~14,28.697590,77.143108,2.63211107261,13.1314821232~64,28.        683058,77.079048,2.10283926574,28.9526789043~66,28.670294,77.126684,2.8317092358    ,5.80484607006~67,28.677712,77.092713,1.95077211146,28.4871314757~68,28.665512,7    7.093081,2.76955528898,21.8407451837~71,28.674069,77.124547,2.53467055409,24.755    4907651~"
?>
```

Comment: Add error reporting to your php code by appending  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your php script, what does it return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to provide the **full path** to the python script, i.e.:

```
python /full/path/to/recommend.py
```

---

As mentioned on my comments, in order to properly debug `php`, you'll need to **enable error reporting** at the top of your php scripts , i.e.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
//the rest of your code...
```

Comment on production mode.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the help. It worked. However, I am encountering a problem in my Python script. I've started a new discussion :
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646992/error-in-python-script-regarding-strsys-argv1)

Thankyou.

Comment: The problem on your new question is related to the php shell_script cod and not python. I'm on mobile, when I'm on the pc I'll answer you.