# Error in Python Script regarding str(sys.argv[1])

Tags: php, python, arguments, parameter-passing

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import math
import sys 
from decimal import Decimal

conn=mdb.connect('localhost','root','','testdb')
c=conn.cursor()

user_id=str(sys.argv[1])
lati=str(sys.argv[2])
longi=str(sys.argv[3])
radius=int(str(sys.argv[4]))

#user_id=1
#lati='28.635308'
#longi='77.224960'
#radius=1.5
```

The error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\recommend.py", line 9, in <module>
    user_id=str(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However the dummy values which is commented by # are working fine. Any help in resolving this error ?

Comment: How are you running this script?

Comment: I am calling it using shell_exec() command from my PHP page.
The eroor is indicated in the Python Idle Shell.

Comment: I mean, are you passing the 4 parameters in the call? what is the exact command you are invoking?

Comment: `<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$lat = $_POST['lt'];
$lon = $_POST['ln'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$rad = $_POST['rd'];
#$lat = "28.674558";
#$lon = "77.274202";
#$uid = "1";
#$rad = "1";
$outs = 'python C:\Python27\recommend.py ' . $uid . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . ' ' .     $rad;
$output = shell_exec($outs);
echo $output;
?>`

Comment: I think this last comment is very useful. you should include it in the original question so that php people may help you too

Comment: It may also help your debugging to have `echo $outs;` in the PHP, just to make sure that the command you're running has managed to look like you're expecting it to

Answer (score 2):

One way to checking the mistake you can print out the **sys.argv** list and check the number of elements it has. The output of the error was saying there is only one element (most probably it's the script's itself -script name-) in the **sys.argv**. Most probably when you are running the script you don't supply the arguments(you must supply 4 arguments).

Comment: `<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$lat = $_POST['lt'];
$lon = $_POST['ln'];
$uid = $_POST['id'];
$rad = $_POST['rd'];
#$lat = "28.674558";
#$lon = "77.274202";
#$uid = "1";
#$rad = "1";
$outs = 'python C:\Python27\recommend.py ' . $uid . ' ' . $lat . ' ' . $lon . ' ' .     $rad;
$output = shell_exec($outs);
echo $output;
?>`                                               I have called the scripts with four arguments  Is there any error in this ?

Comment: I had some experiment on your Python and PHP file and I'm not sure but the line `radius=int(str(sys.argv[4]))` is not compatible (because the string can not be cascade to int the function must be float). You can try this `radius=float(str(sys.argv[4]))` . I hope it fix your problem.